# Swift XCTestCase creating a tableView can't dequeue cells?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, xctest

So I'm trying to write some layout tests for my Swift table view. I have created a sample test project that shows my problem, and I've uploaded it to a google drive [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3QHH8lXsFaEcENSY01yZEFCWEU/view?usp=sharing)

Basically, if you try and run the tests, `testTheTest` fails because it tries to call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` on the faked table view, but gets nil for the cell. However, it works when building and running the project normally, and there are properly 10 cells shown (you can know because 10 cells are selectable).

What is going on here? Why is my test case table view not able to dequeue a cell, while my regular table view is able to?

Comment: I don't have the time to look into the project. Did you tell the test table view that it has cells for this identifier (for example by calling `registerNib...` or `registerClass...`)?

Comment: Check if the xib is available in the test target.

Comment: That was it! I register the class in the TableViewController itself, but I wasn't in the test. I am in both now and it works! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. TableView register nib again in XCTestCase, before Calling `cellForRow` function.(For `viewDidLoad` will not be automatic called)
2. Use `let cell = self.vc.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0))` instead of `let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0))`

[image]